# load wordpress website offline and search on it

Tags: android, wordpress, web, offline

I want to download my site and use in my app.
I have downloaded(web2disk,httrack...) but the search does not work and the icons do not show up.
I want to use the entire webiste offline somebody has an ide

Answer (score 0):

That would be mostly impossible because the search must hit the database. One idea is to replace the search page that shows on your app with your own search, crawling through your offline files.

Comment: I also thought so
you might have an ide: files to search from HTML to search for example C:/example/   but in a webpage not in windows or mac 
That would be a solution